Call QLPreviewController toolbar action programmatically
We are implementing our custom subclassed QLPreviewController.
Indeed we subclassed and customized it since we do not want its 'Save to Files', 'Print', 'Share' options to be shown to the user. For this purpose, we used Lukas' solution suggestion in this page and hid both navigation bar at the top and toolbar at the bottom. After all just placed a 'back' button over its hidden toolbar and it is seen as such 
Everything upto now was nice so far, but we do not want to lose 'search' feature of QLPreviewController because it is good enough. Normally this functionality can be accessed inside bottom toolbar of QLPreviewController by the user and another popup appears if clicked. 
Just to test it, when we made our blocking bottom view's height lesser and let this 'search' button be visible and clicked, this search popup is laying out over our blocking view, so this is enough for us to use it. The search item button is normally existing inside bottom toolbar (before we hide it with a blocking view) as shown in the picture

Hence all we need to do is, making that search button (which is staying under our blocking bottom view) action be called programmatically.
We have already searched it in stackoverflow and over internet, but almost all questions are about customizing it, hiding buttons or any other appearance things etc. Any help and assistance will be kindly appreciated by us.
